# Spring MVC Integration with Thymeleaf + Existing JSP apache tiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, thymeleaf, tiles

I am trying to configure Thymeleaf Html page with Spring MVC. I have controller method from which I am trying to return he thymeleaf template html page. Its existing project which uses spring mvc + tiles.I need to integrate thymeleaf in to existing project. The template Engine is autowired which is coming from different Jar file. I have provided configuration below. I am not getting any exception but getting Page Not found when I try to load the page.

IS it possible to have one flow which resolves view with Tiles  + Jps and another flow with Thymeleaf template. how can I achieve it .

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/thymeleafConfiguration")
   public class ConfigController {

    @Autowired
    TemplateEngine templateEngine; // This class is coming from different jar and I have 
                                    //autowired. xml configuration is provided for reference
    
    
    @PostConstruct   // Changes needs to apply only to certain class so I am using 
                        //postconstruct method in controller 
                        // where I need to use thymeleaf template. 
    public void Init() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/thymeleafPage/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
 
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/view") // controller method where I am redirecting thymeleaf 
                                         page
    public String  viewTemplate(){      
        return "thymeleaf";
    }
}
```

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="thymeleafProcessor" class="com.java.ThymeleafTemplateProcessor">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="htmlStringTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver">
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true" />
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="htmlStringTemplateResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Project Structure :

```
  myProject
  |
  |Src 
        -Java
        
        -templates
          -thymeleafPage        
            - thymeleaf.html
            
        -webContent
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Can you please guide me how can I load the Page. I have referred documentation of thymeleaf
[ThymeleafDocumetation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-tiles-integration)
[Tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#integrating-thymeleaf-with-spring)

I have followed some examples but couldnt find much difference. I appreciate your help.
Jordan

Comment: @ndrone  can you guys guide me for it.. its similar problem which you discussed. Need to integrate thymeleaf html page. existing code uses tiles + jsps.

Comment: @Harmeet Singh Taara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution how to make it work for Jsp , HTML and Thymeleaf template together.
Thank you